# Image animation in java swing on click

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, animated-gif

Say I have a `JFrame` and a `JButton` in it. I want to display an animated (`.gif`) image once I click the button. While another event (say `ActionEvent e`) stops displaying the animation in the `JFrame`. What should be my approach?

Comment: @EranMedan :i think that he want to `start` and `stop` the animation , not just about to display it

Comment: I guess I am neither trying to just display the image nor having an issue with the frames, so these suggestions are not helping.

Comment: *"I want to display an animated (`.gif` preferably) image once I click the button."*  GIF is the only format that supports animations.  So saying 'preferably' just confuses people.  I am guessing the important bit is 'animation'.  Please confirm, and edit your question so it is more clear.

Comment: `these suggestions are not helping.` Then maybe you should ask a clear question. People are trying their best with the information given.

Comment: <head-desk />  Removing the word 'preferably' does not solve anything.

Comment: I am concerned about an animated GIF image , that's all. @AndrewThompson, please help with the edit if you can think of some better words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Display the 1st image (animation frame) in a `JLabel`.  When the user clicks the button, start a Swing `Timer` that changes the icon of the label to the next frame(s), looping once it has shown all frames.  When the user clicks the button again, stop the animation.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

class Chomper {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Image[] frames = {
            ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUmOD.png")),
            ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKyiD.png")),
            ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4maMm.png")),
            ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn9V5.png"))
        };
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

                final JLabel animation = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(frames[0]));
                gui.add(animation, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                ActionListener animate = new ActionListener() {

                    private int index = 0;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (index<frames.length-1) {
                            index++;
                        } else {
                            index = 0;
                        }
                        animation.setIcon(new ImageIcon(frames[index]));
                    }
                };
                final Timer timer = new Timer(200,animate);

                final JToggleButton b = new JToggleButton("Start/Stop");
                ActionListener startStop = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (b.isSelected()) {
                            timer.start();
                        } else {
                            timer.stop();
                        }
                    }
                };
                b.addActionListener(startStop);
                gui.add(b, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you access individual frames/images from the gif?

Comment: The source of the images is seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14437899/418556).

Comment: +1, You updated the source while I was posting my answer. I was wondering what an internal frame had to do with this.

Comment: @camickr Sorry, I have butter-copy-fingers tonight.  That stuff with internal frames was the source from another answer.  :P

Comment: I figured as much, I do that lots of times as well :)

Comment: This is really good. That means I need access to the individual frames, one or the other way, to do that. but thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to get the frame/images from a gif, but if you have access to them, then you can use the [Animated Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/animated-icon/) class to do the animation for you. It uses a Timer behind the scenes to do the animation so you can simply start/stop/pause the Timer as you wish.