# Java Swing + Timer? Moving a line across JPanel

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, java-2d

What I'm trying to do is simple. I have a JLayeredPane with two panels inside of it. Panel 2 (higher Z index) has a transparent background and only displays a Line2D element that goes from Y = 0 to Y = max. I need the X value to increment every so many milliseconds, and then redraw the line. I have everything set up to do so, except I can't figure out how to do the bar movement via timing.

I've done some research and every time I saw mentions of the timer class (Which I feel would be able to accomplish what I'm trying to do) people recommend not using it. I can't figure out an alternative to using the timer class in order to slide my bar across the screen.

Comment: Your question is a bit off since you say "*people* recommend not using it", but provide no backup for this statement. Who is recommending not to use the Timer and what is their rationale? I would say try doing this with a Timer. If it doesn't work, come on back with your code.

Comment: Are you referring to `java.util.Timer` or `javax.swing.Timer` (e.g. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9772978/418556), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16040330/418556))?  The latter is fine, the former requires a little extra work to ensure that GUI updates are done on the EDT.  Please link to the best example of this information you refer to.  Your question is currently confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I'll look into swing's timer and come back once I have some code. I tried to recreate the searches that recommended against using the timer, but I wasn't able to find it. I'll come back with links if I get them!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps you. It does exactly what you want.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FloorPlaner extends JFrame {
     public int x=0;

     public FloorPlaner(){ 
          super("FloorPlaner");

          requestFocus(); 

          setContentPane(new DrawingPane());

          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

          setSize(400, 400);

          setResizable(true); 

          setVisible(true); 

          while (true) { 
              x++;
              repaint();
              try {
              Thread.sleep(40); //25 FPS
              } catch(InterruptedException bug) {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              System.out.println(bug);
              }
          }
     }


     class DrawingPane extends JPanel { //Where you actually draw on
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //Drawing method
           g.drawLine(x,0,x,400);
        }   
     }
     public static void main(String args[]) {
            new FloorPlaner(); //Start it
     }
}
```