# Java pong can't move both paddles at once

Tags: java, swing, keypress, pong

Trying to make pong in java but can't move both paddles at once. You can move one or the other but not both at the same time. Do I need to create 2 threads with 2 different pannels?

Here is where I am specifying the key events

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON){
               if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                   y-=10;
               }

         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                        y+=10;
                }

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE){
                ytwo-=10;
        }
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON){
                        ytwo+=10;
                }

        }
        }
```

Here is the full code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Pong extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

        //implement constants

        PongPanel pongPanel = new PongPanel();  

        //JFrame pong x and y coordinates 
        static final int jfpX = 150;
        static final int jfpY = 20;

        // JFrame pong width and height
        static final int jfpW = 800;
        static final int jfpH = 600;

        Thread thrd;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Pong jfp = new Pong();
                jfp.setVisible(true);

        }

        public Pong(){
                setBounds(jfpX,jfpY,jfpW,jfpH); 
                setTitle("Pong");
                setResizable(false);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                setBackground(Color.black);


                add(pongPanel);
                addKeyListener(pongPanel);
                thrd = new Thread (pongPanel);
        thrd.start();
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }



}

class PongPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener{
        Random random = new Random();
        static final int jpW = 800;
        static final int jpH = 600;
        int paddleStart = (jpH/2)-35;
        int paddleStarttwo = (jpH/2)-35;
        int ballStartX = (jpW/2)-20;
        int ballStartY = (jpH/2)-20;
        int ytwo,x,y;
        int ballD = 30;
        int paddleW1 = 20;
        int paddleH1 = 100;
        int paddleW2 = 20;
        int paddleH2 = 100;
        int min = -2;
        int max = 2;
        int randomBallx, randomBally;
//        int randomBallx = random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
//        int randomBally = random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;

        int rand1 = random.nextInt(2-1 + 1)+1; // random for function to determine ballx and bally
        int rand2 = random.nextInt(2-1+2)+1;
        int dx = 4;
        int dy = 4; //direction of y

        public void ballNotZero(){// makes sure the ball doesnt go straight up and down
        if (randomBallx ==0){
              randomBallx = random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
             }
             if(randomBally == 0){
              randomBally=random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
             }
//         if(rand1 ==1){
//         randomBallx=-1;
//         }
//         if(rand1 ==2){
//         randomBallx=1;
//         }
//         if(rand2 ==1){
//         randomBally =-1;
//         }
//         if(rand2==2){
//         randomBally = 1;
//         }

        }


        public PongPanel(){

        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Color ball;
        Color paddleOne;
        Color paddleTwo;
        ball = new Color(255,0,255);
        paddleOne = new Color(255,0,0);
        paddleTwo = new Color(0,0,255);


        g.setColor(ball);
        g.fillOval(ballStartX+randomBallx,ballStartY+randomBally,ballD,ballD);

        g.setColor(paddleOne);
        g.fillRect(20,paddleStart+y,paddleW1,paddleH1);

        g.setColor(paddleTwo);
        g.fillRect(760,paddleStarttwo+ytwo,paddleW2,paddleH2);



        }
        public void run() {
                while(true){
                ballNotZero(); 
                detectPaddle();
                randomBall();
                ballMove();
                repaint();
        try {Thread.sleep(75); } catch(Exception e){

        };

                }
        }
        public static boolean intervallContains(int low, int high, int n) { //determines if something is in a certain range
            return n >= low && n <= high;
        }
        public void detectPaddle(){  //determines if ball is close enough to paddle for detection
        int withinY = (paddleStart+y) -(ballStartY+randomBally);
        int withinY1 = (paddleStarttwo+ytwo)-(ballStartY+randomBally);

        if (ballStartX+randomBallx <=20  &&  intervallContains(-50,50,withinY)){
        dx = -dx;
        }
        if(ballStartX+randomBallx >=760 && intervallContains(-50,50,withinY1)){
        dx = -dx;
        }
        }

        public void randomBall(){
        if(randomBallx >=0 ){
        randomBallx+=dx;
        }
        if(randomBallx<0){
        randomBallx-=dx;
        }
        if(randomBally>=0){
        randomBally+=dy;
        }
        if(randomBally<0){
        randomBally-=dy;
        }
//                randomBallx+=randomBallx;
//                randomBally+=randomBally;
        }
        public void ballMove(){
        if(ballStartY+randomBally > jpH-60){
        dy= -dy;

        }
        if(ballStartY+randomBally <0){
        dy = -dy;
        }
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON){
               if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                   y-=10;
               }

         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                        y+=10;
                }

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE){
                ytwo-=10;
        }
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON){
                        ytwo+=10;
                }

        }
        }



        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with threads? It seems like you could easily do this as a single-threaded program

Comment: Right now there is only one thread for everything. I am not sure how to get them both to go at the same time

Comment: @RobWatts: Please explain how this can be accomplished in a single threaded program? I for the life of me cannot imagine how this is possible and am very intrigued by your suggestion. Please offer details so I can learn from you.

Comment: Why are you first checking `if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON)` and then check the keys individually again?

Comment: I did it before without the if (this or this or this or this), and it wasnt working so i tried that but it still doesnt work

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: By single-threaded, I mean he doesn't have to create any threads himself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Threads with Key Bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999506/threads-with-key-bindings)

Answer (score 4):

- Don't use `while (true)` but rather a Swing timer.
- Don't use KeyListeners but rather Key Bindings.
- Consider turning on a Swing Timer (which can act as your "background thread") that moves one paddle when the bindings detect the correct key has been pressed,
- and stopping the timer that moves the paddle when the same key is released.
- Same for the other paddle but of course having its actions respond to a bindings of a different pair of keys.
- When attempting to get something like this working, try to get it working in a very simple program first, one without all the other junk required for your main program, but one which will allow you to test and prove your concept. Then if you get things working in your small program, great, you add the functionality to your main program. And if your small program code doesn't work and you need our help, you can post the small self-contained program here (an [sscce](http://sscce.org)) for us to test and modify.

Comment: Here's an example of using a timer: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/examples/animation/40BouncingBall/bouncingball.html

Comment: Would the first key pressed have to be released before the second key is pressed to move the other paddle?

Comment: @AxGryndr: no, since their bindings are independent and they would activate their own timers.