# I cannot get keyboard input in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keyboard-events

I have a JFrame that has two panels, the first panel(panel) has buttons and labels only, where the second panel has the game and keyboard input . The second panel(panelGame) does appear on screen, but with no keyboard response, my space ship cannot move nor I can shoot. Please download my project and help me thank you for your time and consideration.

https://www.mediafire.com/?wjz6fm3z4567bq8

Comment: Post relevant code here.

Comment: You're better off posting your 'panelGame' class code here. How do we know that's not malicious code? Also, have you added a KeyListener to the panel?

Comment: You should consider using key bindings to the frame.

Comment: `test8.java` Line 155 looks like the problem to me.

Answer (score 3):

From the description of the problem, the likely cause is you are using a `KeyListener` of some kind

The problem with this is, a `KeyListener` will only be notified of key events when the component it is registered to has key board focus AND is focusable.

A better solution would be to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which allow you to control at what focus level the bindings should be triggered.

Comment: A related example is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14001011/230513).