# Stop windows Key Input Delay in Java

Tags: java, keyevent

I am creating a side scrolling game and currently when I press an arrow key, the character moves, pauses then moves indefinitely until the key is released.

The pause comes from Windows configuration with Key Delay, so you don't accidentally type in duplicate key presses if you hold down the key too long.

I want to know if there is a way to get rid of this.

Here is my code for key presses:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke){}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke){}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke){
    int code = ke.getKeyCode();

    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        if(playerY > 0){
            playerY-=speed;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        if(playerY < 600){
            playerY+=speed;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        if(playerX < 800){
            playerX+=speed;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        if(playerX > 0){
            playerX-=speed;
            System.out.println(playerX);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the key is pressed, you should set some variable by which you determine movement. On KeyReleased you unset this variable.

The way how you handle this it to call the method, for example moveLeft(), and in loop you are checking this variable. On KeyReleased, when you redefine it, the loop ends.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just created 4 booleans for up down left and right, and in my run method depending on which boolean is true, it will execute a movement and then delay it by 10 ms

Comment: Btw. this question was already asked several times, for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999506/threads-with-key-bindings)..

Comment: Yet none of the questions are titled like mine. I know how to do key events, just was unsure how to go about getting rid of the delay.